# Global lexical-binding setting?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, lexical-binding

I've seen `;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-` at the top of a file and `(setq lexical-binding t)` as how to turn on lexical binding for elisp code, but is there a way to tell Emacs to simply always do lexical binding, i.e., in your init file? From what I've seen, my guess would be it's a buffer-only option. Also, how can lexical binding be turned on in an org file? Does each babel emacs lisp code block have to specify `(setq lexical-binding t)`? BTW, putting `;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-` is not dealt with well on an export to HTML, etc. Using version 26.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Elisp

AFAIK the only two reliable ways for using lexical binding in Elisp files are:

1. Setting the buffer-local variable `lexical-binding` as file-local variable at the beginning of the Elisp file with
   `;;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-`
2. Using `eval` with non-nil `LEXICAL` argument. (`LEXICAL` can be t or the lexical environment to be used)

Motivation for that behavior is that a global setting would potentially break your emacs configuration. Lexical binding in Elisp is a relatively new feature and older packages can rely on dynamic binding. See the difference in the behavior of `lex-p` below for both variants of binding.

## Org-mode

I don't know where you got `(setq lexical-binding t)` from. That just does not work as the following Org source block shows:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq lexical-binding t)
(defun lex-p ()
  "Return t if lexical binding is in effect."
  (let (lex
    _lex-p)
    (let ((lex t))
      (setq _lex-p
        (lambda ()
          lex)))
    (funcall _lex-p)))

(if (lex-p) "Yes" "No")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: No
```

Nevertheless there is the header argument `:lexical` for Org source block that just does what you want:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :lexical t
(defun lex-p ()
  "Return t if lexical binding is in effect."
  (let (lex
    _lex-p)
    (let ((lex t))
      (setq _lex-p
        (lambda ()
          lex)))
    (funcall _lex-p)))

(if (lex-p) "Yes" "No")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Yes
```

You can set that header argument file global by the `header-args` property:

```org
#+PROPERTY: header-args:emacs-lisp :lexical t

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun lex-p ()
  "Return t if lexical binding is in effect."
  (let (lex
    _lex-p)
    (let ((lex t))
      (setq _lex-p
        (lambda ()
          lex)))
    (funcall _lex-p)))

(if (lex-p) "Yes" "No")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Yes

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(if (lex-p) "Foo" "Bar")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Foo
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Still, in the second code block I see `#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :lexical t` but the next line is `(setq lexical-binding t)`. You say above the second is ineffective? What was your thinking there?

Comment: @147pm Thanks for the note.  The presence of  `(setq lexical-binding t)` in the second block was a copy-paste error. I have corrected it.

Comment: `(setq lexical-binding t)` is needed to use lexical-binding in `*scratch*`.

Comment: @npostavs if I put the code from the first code block into `*scratch*`, change the `(if (lex-p) "Yes" "No")` into `(message (if (lex-p) "Yes" "No"))` and evaluate the buffer with `M-x eval-buffer` I get the message `"No"`. On the other hand if I put the stuff from the second source block into the scratch buffer wrap the last form into `message` and wrap everything by a `(eval '(progn ...) t)` I get a `"Yes"`.

Comment: @npostavs Even more important: If I put the stuff from second source block into `*scratch*` with the last form wrapped in `(message ...)`, **insert `;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-` at the beginning** of the buffer, and run `M-x eval-buffer` I get a `"Yes"`.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I never `eval-buffer` in `*scratch*`. I was thinking of `eval-last-sexp` (`C-x C-e`) or `eval-defun` (`C-M-x`).

Comment: @npostavs I can imagine that `eval-last-sexp` works since `elisp--eval-last-sexp` calls `eval` with `lexical-binding` as its `LEXICAL` argument. interestingly `eval-region` respects the current buffer-local value of `lexical-binding` while `eval-buffer` does not. Maybe the motivation is that `eval-buffer` can "look" at the beginning of the buffer while `eval-region` should not.

Comment: I have just discovered `auto-insert-mode` via [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7y000a/how_to_add_lexicalbinding_t_to_every_new_elisp/). It might be handy to know about, very convenient! For me the behavior of just activating `auto-insert-mode` is fine enough, no need to use the hooks etc. as mentioned in the (currently) most popular comment there...

Comment: About the scratch buffer, if the buffer is in `lisp-interaction-mode` then, as mentioned in the docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html), `lexical-binding` is `t`, in any other mode AFAIK, it is `nil`.